# Does mongodb require connection on each operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So i am very new to `mongodb` and i wish to use it in my application. Now i **HATE** redundant code but reading up on how to use mongodb with node.js it seems that there is a pattern where you always have to connect before making any CRUD operation.

**Example from the offical documentation**:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  insertDocument(db, function() {
      db.close();
  });
});
```

My question is. is it possible to make a middleware that keeps the connection open so you only has to call `insertDocument` (in the above example)  ?

Comment: better you use mongoose.connect() and keep it in config file. and you can use anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea of course, just keep the `db` variable around until you don't need it any longer - then call `close()`

```
var mdb;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  mdb = db;
  insertDocument(mdb, function() {
      // ...
  });
});

// do other stuff with mdb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) as you mentioned middleware.

The connection is only opened once (on the global scope) and then you can use it throughout the app.